# Intento adapatar Python a Sublime Text pero me muestra el siguiente mensaje por pantalla: there are no packages available for installation

Tags: python

Package Control: Error downloading channel. HTTP error 404 downloading https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Comment: Por lo visto tienen un problema y el archivo está corrupto. Tienes más información [aquí](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/1397). También han dejado una solución temporal en dicho hilo, para que puedas seguir trabajando.

Comment: ya instalastes el package control? mira esto [package control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation)

Comment: Ya instale package control pero aun así no puedo adaptar python

Answer (score 0):

esta es la solución temporal cambiar el canal del control de paquetes

"channels": [ "https://erhan.in/channel_v3.json" ],
to Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings - User file.

This is the latest snapshot of the original JSON file from web.archive.org.

Comment: no es válido ni bien visto dejar múltiples respuestas para la misma pregunta

Comment: borra una y deja la otra por favor